# @PersistenceContext is not applicable to parameters. How to inject EntityManager through a constructor?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

It is a best practice to use constructor injection. However I can't acheive this with `@PersistenceContext`.

I would like to have the following constructor:

```
private final EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public MyService(@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

But I can't since `@PersistenceContext` is only applicable to `TYPE`, `METHOD` and `FIELD`.

**Q:** How do I inject *a container-managed* `EntityManager` through constructor injection?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, doesn't dropping the `@PersistenceContext` work for you? Injecting an `EntityManager` via `@Autowired` should work just as well

Comment: @crizzis will it inject the same entity manager that is injected with `@PersistenceContext`? I can't find any documentation proving this.

Comment: if you're using spring boot : probably yes because spring is your container. If you're using spring MVC within some application server : probably not because `@Autowired` searches for *any **matching** bean*, meaning you **might** very well catch the container-managed `EntityManager`. You can make sure to get your own if you specify a custom `EntityManagerFactory`

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using spring so your solution will be rather easy :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyPersistenceContainer
{
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public EntityManager getEntityManager()
{
return em;
}
}
```

And now you can simply inject an instance of this class in your constructor, it will always hold a valid EntityManager (because of the bean scope). Mind you : in a web environment you probably should use `@SessionScope` or even `@RequestScope` instead of prototype, this will save resources

---

But there is something to consider :

> When using singleton-scoped beans that have dependencies on beans that
>   are scoped as prototypes, please be aware that dependencies are
>   resolved at instantiation time. This means that if you dependency
>   inject a prototype-scoped bean into a singleton-scoped bean, a brand
>   new prototype bean will be instantiated and then dependency injected
>   into the singleton bean... but that is all. That exact same prototype
>   instance will be the sole instance that is ever supplied to the
>   singleton-scoped bean, which is fine if that is what you want.
>
> However, sometimes what you actually want is for the singleton-scoped
>   bean to be able to acquire a brand new instance of the
>   prototype-scoped bean again and again and again at runtime. In that
>   case it is no use just dependency injecting a prototype-scoped bean
>   into your singleton bean, because as explained above, that only
>   happens once when the Spring container is instantiating the singleton
>   bean and resolving and injecting its dependencies. If you are in the
>   scenario where you need to get a brand new instance of a (prototype)
>   bean again and again and again at runtime, you are referred to the
>   section entitled Section 4.3.7, “Method Injection”

So if you want to inject your "entity manager container-bean" into singleton beans **(which is the default scope)**, have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-method-injection

---

### Its rather important to set your scopes correctly, otherwise you might have (and will have) database inconsistencies, deadlocks or worse

Comment: Please, notice that the question is  **"How do I inject a container-managed EntityManager through constructor injection?"**, Not how create a request scope component.  , [here are some advantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366225/208886) Using constructors instead of field dep injection

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood it now. You talked about session scope but aren't all spring components Singleton by default? I work with web apps and had no issues on that, because these components are stateless, EntityManager and JdbTemplate  have some state but they use ThreadLocal for this

Comment: thats exactly the problem - singleton beans **can hold a state** and webapps should be state**less** - this will cause the possible re-use of a cached EntityManager if you dont select your scopes correctly. Re-using entitymanagers generally is a bad idea, it will cause lost updates and concurrency issues. Also : most containers will close the entitymanager after the DB-session has ended, in which case it wont even be possible to use it anymore

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in your solution **you still inject entity manager through field injection** which is exactly want I want to get rid of in my code.

Comment: you can exchange the field injection for method injection or even do a programmatic container lookup but i dont get the point - CDI is extremely stable, proven and efficient nowadays, it will be **really** hard to beat it; even spring CDI is pretty much as good as it gets

Answer (score 0):

It sould be possible using Spring Data. But if you would not like to use Spring Data in your project for some reason (e.g. you're just making a legacy project a bit better), you can create the following `FactoryBean` to make `EntityManager` injectable via constructor injection:

```
/**
 * Makes the {@link EntityManager} injectable via <i>@Autowired</i>,
 * so it can be injected with constructor injection too.
 * (<i>@PersistenceContext</i> cannot be used for constructor injection.)
 */
public static class EntityManagerInjectionFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<EntityManager> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return EntityManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager createInstance() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Please note, that because we use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation internally, the returned `EntityManager` will be a proper thread-safe proxy, as it would have been injected directly at the place of usage with field injection.